# Binding custom header element

Tags: angular

My problem is, i have a component 'action-bar' which is supposed to have a header. But i would also like to have the freedom of being able to insert h1,h2,h3 etc. With binding, so the component can be called and title set.

Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'action-bar',
  templateUrl: 'action-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['action-bar.component.styl']
})

export class ActionBarComponent {

}
```

Template:

```
<div class="action-bar">
    <ng-content select="[action-bar-title]">
    </ng-content>
</div>
```

Thus in my component using it. I would do

```
<action-bar>
    <div action-bar-title>
<h1>Hi</h1>
    </div>
</action-bar>
```

But how would i make the h1 bindable to action-bar component? so that i can even use a h2 or h3.

Or is my mindset about angular 2 wrong, should there just be 'a' header, then maybe a size attribute or class to switch the header size.

Im still learning

With thanks.

Comment: What do you mean `how would i make the h1 bindable to action-bar component?`?

Comment: So that i can make a function on the component, which will change the content of the h1,h2,h3 (whichever has been put in)

Answer (score 0):

> i have a component 'action-bar' which is supposed to have a header. But i would also like to have the freedom of being able to insert h1,h2,h3 etc. With binding, so the component can be called and title set

You could use `innerHTML` template syntax, so you can insert some html tags. But beware of its security risk involved, should not use it for user input.

```
<div [innerHTML]="actionBarTitle"></div>
```

`actionBarTitle` is your class instances property, and its value can be change programmatically.

Example [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HzZajKLMw5jOgMuS7x4I?p=preview)